# Send email through smtp in superlance using crashmail

Tags: python, email, sendmail, supervisord

I'm trying to set up the email sending when a process changes state in [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) by using [crashmail](https://superlance.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crashmail.html). Having no luck with the default `sendmail` program which requires quite a lot of setup, I decided to go with a small script in Python that sends email using SMTP.

This worked very well (I received indeed an email saying that the process state changes) for the first state change but stop working afterward. I have tried to change different options in `supervisord` such as `buffer_size` or `autorestart` but it has no effect.

Here is the script I use to trigger the `supervisord` state changes:

```
import time

from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(">>>>> STARTING ...", flush=True)
    while True:
        print("sleep now:", datetime.utcnow(), flush=True)
        time.sleep(30)
        raise Exception("meo meo")
```

This is the script that sends email through Gmail. This one will send the `stdin`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib


def get_server():
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.login("user@gmail.com", "password")
    return smtpserver


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    data = sys.stdin.read()

    s = get_server()
    s.sendmail('from@gmail.com', ['myemail@fitle.com'], data)
    s.quit()
```

Here is my `supervisord.conf`

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=crashmail -a -m myemail@gmail.com -s /home/ubuntu/mysendmail.py
events=PROCESS_STATE
buffer_size=102400
autorestart=true
```

Does anyone have any idea why? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I moved the `eventlistener` section to a separate file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` (instead of putting at the end of `supervisord.conf`) and now everything is working as expected ...

Comment: Thats strange, any idea why it needed to be in a separate file like that? I'm needing to implement a very similar solution i'll probably use ruby however

Comment: not working for me man. I am wondering how this will run if it is moved to `conf.d`. Do we need to run it separately using `supervisord`?